# grep first instance of a pattern with a wildcard

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to use the grep command to find the first instance of a pattern with a wildcard in it. For instance if we have the following line in file "inputFile.txt" with quite a few random things in it:

```
[random 1]=[3], iwfl +34234, [target]=[value], well[], random[]][value
```

Desired Output:

```
[target]=[value]
```

Even better than desired Output:

```
value
```

What I've already tried:

```
cat inputFile.txt | grep -m 1 "[target].*]"
```

I was hoping the wildcard would only match with the first instance of "]" it detects. However, this hasn't been working and selects between [target] and the last "]" in the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need `grep -m 1 '\[target][^]]*]'`

Comment: `grep -o "\[target]=\[[^]]*]" file` should work for you

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `grep` with `-o` option:

```sh
grep -o "\[target]=\[[^]]*]" file

[target]=[value]
```

**Explanation:**

- `\[target]=`: Match text `[target]=`
- `\[`: Match opening `[`
- `[^]]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not `]`
- `]`: Match closing `]`

---

If you want only `value` part then use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/^.*\[target]=\[([^]]*)].*/\1/' file

value
```

Comment: hi @anubhava which of the two do you think would be a faster operation?

Comment: Both use similar regex so both will give similar performance. Did this work for you?